# echo list of products by category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone tell me how to echo data that is relating with another table?

I have a table

```
tbl_category_products:<
- id_categorys
- category
```

And other table for the products

```
tbl_products:
- title
- description
- id_categorys
```

How could I echo the list of products by category in PHP?

Here is some code, but no sucess.
Im trying but no sucess, here is the original code
Table names:
tbl_categorias_noticias
- id_categoria_noticia
- categoria

tbl_noticias
- id_noticia
- id_categoria_noticia
-titulo
-decricao
-msg
-nome_arquivo
-legenda

```
<?php
 $categoryId = 1; 
  $sql_visualizar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias AS t1 JOIN tbl_categorias_noticias c
ON c.id_categoria_noticia=t1.id_categoria_noticia WHERE id_categoria_noticia = {$categoryId}");
while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql_visualizar)){
$titulo = $linha ['titulo'];
$descricao = $linha['descricao'];
$msg = $linha['msg'];
$legenda = $linha['legenda'];
$nome_arquivo = $linha['nome_arquivo'];
$id_noticia = $linha['id_noticia'];

  ?>
```

Comment: products matching a category?

Answer (score 1):

You need a join:

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.description, t2.category
FORM tbl_products t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_category_products t2 ON t1.id_categorys = t2.id_categorys
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

First of all: [mysql connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

```
$categoryId = 1;    
$query = "SELECT t1.* FROM tbl_products AS t1 JOIN tbl_category_products c
ON c.id_categorys=t1.id_categorys WHERE id_categorys = {$categoryId}";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //show your products
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN to query both tables

```
SELECT p.title, p.decription, c.category
FROM tbl_products p
JOIN tbl_category_products c
ON c.id_categorys=p.id_categorys
ORDER BY c.category ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tp.title, tp.description, tcp.category FORM tbl_products tp,tbl_category_products tcp where tp.id_categorys = tcp.id_categorys
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.title, t1.description, t2.category
FORM tbl_products t1
JOIN
tbl_category_products t2 
ON t1.id_categorys = t2.id_categorys
WHERE t1.id_categorys = 'myCategory'
```